# How to send individual Inline Images to Outlook/Gmail account using the Microsoft Power Automation from onedrive

Tags: automation, outlook, office-automation

I am currently working on a project where I need to send individual emails using Power Automation from Outlook. I have successfully achieved this using base64 encoding, but I am encountering an issue. The inline image I attach to the email is not visible in Gmail accounts, although it displays correctly in Outlook.

Is there an alternative method or solution to ensure that the individual inline images are visible to each recipient, regardless of their email client (Outlook or Gmail)?

To provide more context, I have the following columns in my data:

Name
Email
Image_Name

My goal is to extract images from OneDrive using the information in the Image_Name column and include these images in the individual emails I send to the corresponding recipients.

Your assistance and guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

I tried with the follwing method but no luck to achive this in gmail account as it does not have the base64 support. Is there any other method to send an email from outlook excel sheet based on the Image_Name from onedrive.

Get File content - FilID

Compose -

base64(outputs('Get_file_content')?['body'])